# Gezeira Shava - They were taught the word? or the verse?

Tags: mesorah-tradition, gezeira-shava

There's a semi famous idea regarding *gezeira shava*s (learning one law to another context through the use of parallel language in both locations), that *Chazal* had a tradition for which words to use but they didn't necessarily know which verse. This is why there exists disputes all over *Shas* which verses to use.

This idea is expressed by Rashi

> רש"י מסכת קידושין דף יז עמוד א ד"ה מיכה מיכה
>
> אין אדם דן ג"ש מעצמו ומסורה היא להם מרבותיהם ומסיני איזו תיבה נכתבה לג"ש ככל דבר הלמד מחבירו

and Ramban

> השגות הרמב"ן לספר המצוות לרמב"ם שורש ב
> והוי יודע שזה שאמרו חכמים שאין אדם דן גזירה שוה מעצמו אין כונתם לומר שכל גזירה שוה מבוארת להם מסיני ונמסרת להם מפי משה רבינו תלמדו מלה פלונית שבפסוק פלוני ממלה פלונית שבפסוק פלוני ותשוו דין שניהם לענין פלוני. אין הדבר כן. שהרי מצינו אותם חולקין תמיד בהרבה מקומות בענין הזה...‏
>
> אבל הכוונה בגזירה שוה שהיא מסיני לומר שהיא בידם קבלה שדין שחיטה שאינה ראויה נלמד מגזירה שוה דשחיטה שחיטה והיתה סברתו שלרבי מאיר שהנכון ללמוד אותה משחוטי חוץ ויהיה שמה שחיטה ור' שמעון ראה בדעתו שיותר נכון ללמוד אותה מן וטבוח טבח והכן ולא תהיה שחיטה שאינה ראויה נדונת כשחיטה. וכן כולם. ‏

and Halichos Olam (by Rav Yeshua ben Yosef, 15th century)

> הליכות עולם שער רביעי פרק ב אות טז
>
> ואם תאמר א"כ דכל גזירה שוה מקובלת מסיני מה ניתן לנו לדרוש, ועוד בכוליה גמרא פריך מאי חזית דגמרת ממלה פלונית לגמור ממלה פלונית ומאי פריך והא אמרת אין אדם דן גזירה שוה מעצמו וכו'. ועתה דע והבן שרשו של דבר, דכל גזרות שוות נמסרו למשה מסיני סתם ומסרן הכתוב לחכמים איזו גזירה שוה נדון אלא שלא נמסרו בשוה ...ופעמים נאמרו התיבות סתם מלה פלונית תלמוד ממלה פלונית כגון טומאתו טומאתו לגזירה שוה פרק קמא דשבועות ולא נמסרו המקומות והחכמים מבקשים מנוח לתיבות אשר ייטב להם לדורשם בהם. זהו העיקר שעליו סובבת כל הגזירה שוה שבגמרא:‏

I always assumed that this is **exactly what Moshe was given at Sinai**. A list of words. However, I see the Chavos Yair argues that that's impossible, and says for sure Moshe had absolute clarity which verses, and he taught it to the people. Which verse to use is included in the list of things that were forgotten when Moshe died (Temurah 16b, he cites this earlier in the responsa).

> שו"ת חוות יאיר סימן קצב אות ע"ג
>
> לימודים הנלמדים מי"ג מידות הם מסיני כמ"ש וא"כ לא שייך בהם שכחה והרי התלמוד מלא במחלוקת בהם והרי ג"ש שלכ"ע צריך שיהיה ללומד בקבלה עד מרע"ה ובלי ספק שמרע"ה ביאר הג"ש ביאור היטיב והרי נחלקו בה [על"ק דקפ"ו ע"א] מהיכן יליף ג"ש אם מדבר פלוני או מדבר אחר שע"כ כתבו שלפעמים היו מקובלים המלות לבד לא המקומות ולפעמים בהיפך וזה בא ע"י שכחות המלות או המקומות כי חלילה לומר כי קבלת מרע"ה מסיני או מסירתו ליהושוע היה חסר הבנה ואפילו האומר כל התורה מן השמים חוץ מק"ו זה ה"ז אפיקור‏

The Ramban himself also seems to entertain this

> השגות הרמב"ן לספר המצוות לרמב"ם שורש ב
>
> ואומר בשמא כי זה מכלל מה שנשתכח באבלו שלמשה בגזירות שוות

However. the wording of the Halichos Olam seems to preclude this, as he says that Moshe was taught the words, and it's up to the *Chachamim* to figure it out (that's what נדרשת בהן means). Also the Chasam Sofer al HaTorah (Vayikra 22:32) understands this principle this way (otherwise his whole *shtickle* there makes no sense).

Now, after all this background info, I have a question on the Chavos Yair (and I guess the Ramban). If the verses were given to Moshe at Sinai, how could that be? There are *gezeira shavas* from verses in Vayikra, Bamidbar, Devarim, regarding events that didn't occur yet. For example, תוך תוך, for אין דברים שבקדושה פחות מעשרה, is learned out from Korach (הבדלו מתוך העדה הזאת). How can we say that Moshe knew that Korach would have a rebellion? This is a question people ask how Moshe got the whole Torah at Sinai, when it takes away free will, and the answer is he received the laws but not the verses (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2181/1739) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59958/1739)). According to this, he did receive at least some verses!

What am I missing? This seems like an obvious question...

Comment: Presumably Moshe received those "at Sinai" in the same sense as the entirety of Torah was received "at Sinai."

Comment: go on..........I already addressed the difference.

Comment: What difference? I'm just saying if there are specific parts of Torah that weren't immediately revealed to Moshe at Sinai, then the gz"sh involving those parts could also have been omitted at the time.

Comment: I'm saying that according to these authorities the verses of future events were revealed to Moshe at Sinai and he taught them to the people...

Comment: Who says Moshe was told who will be the ones to rebel? - there are no names in that verse

Comment: Also, the Ran on Megillah 13a says that that Gezeirah Shavah is an Asmachta, which is Derabanan

Comment: I don't think there's any real dispute that the whole Torah was given to Moshe at Sinai (see Megillah 19b, Yerushalmi Peah 2:4, etc.). The only question is what exactly that means: whether it's a figure of speech, or part of a process, or details were lost or only hinted to. Whatever explanation you go with can probably be applied to the Chavos Yair.

Comment: @שלום that was just an example, but I hear